# Calculating hash in parallel by multiple threads and adding the outputs in an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency

I've written the following code in order to calculate the hash of a `String` (based on SHA-256) and then inserting all the outputs in an `ArrayList<String>` :

```
        ArrayList<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        ArrayList<String> threadListStr = new ArrayList<String>();
        int threadNumber = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
            String tId = String.valueOf(i);
            Thread thr = new Thread(() -> {
                threadListStr.add(calculateHash(tId));
            });
            threadList.add(thr);
        }

        // START the threads
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
            threadList.get(i).start();
        }
        // STOP the threads
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
            threadList.get(i).interrupt();
        }

        System.out.println("Size of ArrayList<String> is: " + threadListStr.size());
        System.out.println("Size of ArrayList<Thread> is: " + threadList.size());
        
        /////////////////////
        
        public static String calculateHash(String tId) {
        String tIdStr = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(tId);
        return tIdStr;
        }
```

However, the `ArrayList<String>` does not become complete and as you see after running the code 5 times, each time, `ArrayList<String>` has a different size (despite the `ArrayList<Thread>` threadList is always complete, as the number of threads is 100.)

```
//1th run
Size of ArrayList<String> is: 60
Size of ArrayList<Thread> is: 100

//2nd run
Size of ArrayList<String> is: 30
Size of ArrayList<Thread> is: 100

//3rd run
Size of ArrayList<String> is: 10
Size of ArrayList<Thread> is: 100

//4th run
Size of ArrayList<String> is: 61
Size of ArrayList<Thread> is: 100

//5th
Size of ArrayList<String> is: 69
Size of ArrayList<Thread> is: 100
```

How should be the code modified so that `ArrayList<String>` stores **all** the outputs **completely**?

**EDITE:** I changed the code as follows, but the output is the same.

```
        ArrayList<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        //ArrayList<String> threadListStr = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> threadListStrSync = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        int threadNumber = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
            String tId = String.valueOf(i);
            Thread thr = new Thread(() -> {
                threadListStrSync.add(calculateHash(tId));
            });
            threadList.add(thr);
        }

        // START the threads
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
            threadList.get(i).start();
        }
        // STOP the threads
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
            threadList.get(i).interrupt();
        }

        System.out.println("Size of ArrayList<String> is: " + threadListStrSync.size());
        System.out.println("Size of ArrayList<Thread> is: " + threadList.size());
```

**Note:** I commented `interrupt();` but the output is still the same.

Comment: @Hulk , I replace `ArrayList<String>` with `Collections.synchronizedList` but the output is the same ...

Comment: @Hulk , I commented `interrupt();` but the output is still the same.

Comment: @Hulk , Perfect, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems

1. either use a threadsafe collection or manually synchronize access - one easy option is to wrap your list with [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))
2. `interrupt()`is not needed, the threads will terminate anyway when they reach the end of their `run()`-method
3. you need to wait for all threads to terminate before printing results - to do that, invoke [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) instead of `interrupt()`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: 1) there may be threads that never get far enough in their execution to add their hash ID to the collection, and 2) the collection of hash IDs is being accessed by multiple threads so you should use a thread safe collection.

```
    ArrayList<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    Collection<String> threadListStr = Collections.synchronizedCollection( new ArrayList<String>() );
    int threadNumber = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
        String tId = String.valueOf(i);
        Thread thr = new Thread(() -> {
            threadListStr.add(calculateHash(tId));
        });
        threadList.add(thr);
    }

    // START the threads
    for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
        threadList.get(i).start();
    }
    // STOP the threads
    for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++) {
       try {
           threadList.get(i).join();
       } catch( InterruptedException exc ) {
           // handle interrupted exception
       }
    }

    System.out.println("Size of ArrayList<String> is: " + threadListStr.size());
    System.out.println("Size of ArrayList<Thread> is: " + threadList.size());
```